# ASP.NET MVC - Validation error messages not displaying value from resource file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, resx

I am globalizing a .net mvc app using Resource (.rex) files.  Everything is working perfectly except when displaying a validation error message: The resource *name* is displayed instead of the value.

[Screenshot of how validation messages are currently displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2C0G.png)

As you can see, the name of the resx property is displayed instead of the value.

The following is the resx file:

[Screenshot of resx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RqK2.png)

Here is how the data annotations on the model properties are set:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resourcefile.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Username_Msg", ErrorMessage = null)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

**[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationErrorRequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorResources))]** 
public string Username { get; set; }

Comment: Are you suggesting to simply swap the attribute order?